# Get reference to const QString

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get a reference to `const QString &a` outside of my function i.e.

```
void function(const QString &a)
{
    //code
}

void otherFunction()
{
    // code <<<<< 
    // I'm unsure how I would be able to get a reference to 
    // const QString &a here and use it. 
}
```

How could I get a reference to `a` in `otherFunction`?

Comment: You could share a `static const QString& var;` but that is poor taste.

Comment: _Why_ would you like to do this? I believe you're trying to achieve something in a complicated way. Try to present a short example where you need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can define QString a as a class member :)
So you can access this variable from any method of your class:

```
classMyCoolClass
{
public:
  void function();
  void otherFunction();    
private:
   QString a;
};
```

Comment: You don't even know whether this functions are part of a class.

Comment: Yes, this is a point, dude - it would be better it was it ;)

Comment: The function 'void function' is a part of a class, it is public.

Comment: Nice, so you can define this variable as a class member as I suggested.

Comment: @Ash Your functions being public members of a class is an awesome important information - you should add this to the question

Comment: This causes an error 'uninitialized reference member MainWindow::a'

Comment: You need to use an object, not a reference, see my or @duDE's sample code. References need to be initialized. Use `QString a`, not `QString& a`.

Comment: I have edited my example as well.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible directly: in `function()`, the **scope** of the `a` parameter is limited to the function itself.

You either need to extend `otherFunction` with a `const QString&` parameter and call it accordingly, or assign the value to a global variable (usually not the preferred way) inside `function()`, so that it can be accessed from `otherFunction()`:

```
static QString str;

void function(const QString& a) {
    str = a;
}

void otherFunction() { 
    qDebug() << str;
}
```

Since you tagged this question with `C++`, the preferred way would be to create a class with a member which holds the `QString`:

```
class Sample {
   QString str;

public:
   void function(const QString& a) { str = a; }

   void otherFunction() { qDebug() << str; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a parameter to `otherFunction()`:

```
void function(const QString &a)
{
    //code
    otherFunction(a);
}

void otherFunction(const QString &a)
{
    //code
    //do stuff with a
}
```